# R error, In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm absolutely beginner using R. Right now I'm trying to do cluster analysis but error occur

↓

```
d.data <- data.frame(FACA = MCR2015$RC1,
                 FACB = MCR2015$RC2,
                 FACC = MCR2015$RC3,
                 FACD = MCR2015$RC4,
                 CLUST = k$cluster)
d.data$CLUST <- factor(d.data$CLUST, levels=c(1:5), labels=c("Ⅰ", "Ⅱ", "Ⅲ", "Ⅳ", "Ⅴ"))
library(MASS)
ld <- lda(CLUST ~ FACA + FACB + FACC + FACD, data = d.data)
ld
plot(ld)
ld_pred=predict(ld, d.data)
> Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

what does this message means? and how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , or give some more info about your `d.data`. If I try to reproduce your code, it works well on the built-in `iris` dataset

```
library(MASS)
data(iris)
str(iris)
ld <- lda(Species ~ ., data = iris)
ld
plot(ld)
ld_pred <- predict(ld, iris[,-5])
```

Maybe the problem is in the factor conversion (`d.data$CLUST <- factor(d.data$CLUST,...)`, `as.factor`is usually used for conversions.
Furthermore, when you use `predict`, you should exclude the outcome variables from the predictors (in your case `d.data$CLUST`).
Posting `str(d.data)` would help (better if you make an example that reproduce your error)